Docusign - how to NOT display the radioButton's value in the tooltip
Case 1: When no tooltip is explicitly set for radio group and If we hover over the radio buttons of docusign it shows tooltip as
Required/Optional - Radio Group name - Radio Button value
Case 2: If we set the tooltip for the radio group then on hover over the radio buttons it displays tooltip:
Required/Optional - Tool Tip message - Radio Button value
I followed the below question and kept the tooltip as zero width space (radioGroup.setTooltip("\u200B");) but it just removes the radio group name from the tooltip
how to NOT display the tab's ID as a tooltip 

Requirement is to show just Required/Optional or just the tooltip message (not to display the radio button value in the tooltip)
We can't keep the radio button's value as empty string as we have radio buttons set as conditional parent for other tabs.
Using Docusign API in a Spring boot application.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4493048/mathew-alden - Reaching out to you if you could help on this one ?

This is the best you can get, you still have to have the word "Required" in there if it's required. You can have something else in addition, but at the minimum it will look like this.
If this is what you want, you simply have to remove the names from the individual radio buttons and that would show like this. Otherwise, it shows the name of the radio buttons in the tooltip. You can also add the tooltip of your choice to show after the word Required, but you cannot completely remove it.


Thanks for the reply. We cannot remove the values of the radio button as there are other tabs/fields dependent on the radio button's value.
We're using the radio button's value to set the Conditional Parent Value for the dependent fields.

The value is not the same as the name. But if you cannot remove the name, not sure you can remove the tooltip. You can try to set the tooltip differently on the buttons vs. the group, but not sure that would work either

Maybe you don't have to use radio buttons at all. What is the use case? how is this being used? It's possible a drop-down and/or checkboxes can be better for you situation ?
